# Optionally calling LUIS from a NodeJS bot built with Botframework

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

I'm trying to build a bot that has a set of known 'commands' that if they match exactly will launch a specific dialog. If the command is not recognised then it passes it to LUIS for natural language processing.

I have tried this approach which seemed to work partially, but when launching prompts, failed to activate the second waterfall step.

```
import builder = require('botbuilder');
let restify = require('restify');

let luisUrl = "MY_LUIS_URL_HERE";

let server = restify.createServer();
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
let bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
let recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisUrl);
let intentsDialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });


let mainLoopDlg = [
    (session, results) => {
        let input = session.message.text.trim();
        if (input === "#mycmd") {
            // Is a command
            session.beginDialog('/mycmd');
        } else {
            // Else assume is a natural language utterance
            // Have tried all of the following
            // Need a way to open a dialog and forward on the original message ...
            intentsDialog.replyReceived(session);
            //session.beginDialog('/intents');
            //session.beginDialog('/intents', { message: session.message });
            //session.beginDialog('/intents', session.dialogData.args);
        }
    }
];

let commandDlg = [
    (session, results) => {
        session.send("Command launched ...");
    }
];

let intentDlg = [
    (session) => {
        builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "hi");
    },
    (session, result) => {
        // THIS IS NEVER REACHED ...
        session.send("Hi" + result.response);
    }
];

bot.dialog('/', mainLoopDlg);
bot.dialog('/mycmd', commandDlg);
bot.dialog('/intents', intentDialog);
intentsDialog.matches('Greeting', intentDlg);

// Grab some secret data from the deploy environment
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log("%s listening to %s", server.name, server.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems I need to use `session.replaceDialog('/intents');` in place of `intentsDialog.replyReceived(session);`

This seems to solve the immediate problem, whether this is watertight I'm not sure. [This issue on the BotFramework Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/462) (which I raised) does something similar for V1.0 of the framework and it seems like there may need to be some state management to keep things in check. For now though the above fix appear to work.